# Extract Names and then separate it with commas

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

```
<td>
<span class="movie_info_actors">
<a href="/?actor_name=Billy Connolly">Billy Connolly</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Craig Ferguson">Craig Ferguson</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Emma Thompson">Emma Thompson</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=John Ratzenberger">John Ratzenberger</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Julie Walters">Julie Walters</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Kelly Macdonald">Kelly Macdonald</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Kevin McKidd">Kevin McKidd</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Patrick Doyle">Patrick Doyle</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Robbie Coltrane">Robbie Coltrane</a>
<a href="/?actor_name=Sally Kinghorn">Sally Kinghorn</a>
</span>
</td>
```

I am trying to extract the actor names and then separate the names with commas using JSoup. For example: Billy Connolly , Craig Ferguson, Emma Thompson

This is my code:

```
String Actor = E.select("span.movie_info_actors").text();
System.out.println(Actor + ", " );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
Elements actors = E.select("span.movie_info_actors > a");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (Element actor : actors) {
    sb.append(actor.text());
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```